# beautifulsoupによって取得したサイトのタイトルをテキストに書き込みたいが、[U+200E]と書き込まれる

Tags: python, python3, beautifulsoup, テキストファイル

beautifulsoupによって取得したサイトのタイトルをテキストに書き込みたいのですが、[U+200E]と書き込まれます。調べたら空白が原因と書かれていたので、空白を削除するコードを追加したのですが、それでも[U+200E]と書き込まれます。どなたか原因がわかる方、何卒宜しくお願い致します。

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# 対象のURL
url = "https://apps.apple.com/jp/app/パズル-ドラゴンズ/id493470467"

try:

    # リクエストを送信してHTMLを取得
    res = requests.get(url)
    # BeautifulSoupオブジェクトを作成
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")

    # titleタグを取得
    title_tags = soup.title
    tag_obj = title_tags.string
    
    tag_obj = tag_obj.strip()
    print(tag_obj, end='*\n')

    with open("all.text",'a',encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write('\ntitle:' + tag_obj)

except Exception:
    word = "取得できませんでした"
    with open("all.text",'a',encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write('\ntitle:' + word)
```

all.text

```
title:‎[U+200E]「パズル＆ドラゴンズ」をApp Storeで
```

Comment: https://apps.apple.com からコンテンツをコピーすることは禁止されているようです。（https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/terms/site.html）

Comment: テキストが表示されていく方向を示すコードのようですね。[第24章 双方向性（BIDI）](https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/ahf_publication/data/xsl-fo-v2/bidi-processing.html), [HOME / 一般句読点 / LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK](https://unicd.net/char/200E), [u200e (国際符号化文字集合・ユニコード U+200E) (@10)](https://glyphwiki.org/wiki/u200e) 等

Comment: `tag_obj = tag_obj.strip(' \t\r\n\u200e')`

Comment: apple.comのコンテンツコピーは禁止なんですね。知らなかったです。気を付けます。